What does $Y-X|X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ mean?
Let $X,Y$ be, respectively, the minimum and the maximum of two i.i.d. random variables with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda>0$. Show that $Y-X|X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$.
What does $Y-X|X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ mean? Is it mean that $Y-X|X=x\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? That is, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have  $f_{Y-X|X}(y|x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(y)$?

This means exactly what you said
